# function argument a pointer array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

in my code I have a array of pointers, where the pointers point to my struct

```
struct Container *bucket[sizeOfHashMap];
```

I have a function that will return 1 of these array pointers (e.g it may return the pointer at array index 6). As an argument it wants a pointer to this pointer. The function can be seen here:

```
struct Container* getWhichBucket(char word[], struct Container **bucket[10]){
    int value = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int size = strlen(word);
    int hashIndex = 0;

    for(i =0; i < size; i++){
      value += (int)word[i];
    }

    //size of array is worked out by getting memory that array takes up / a slot
    hashIndex =  value % sizeOfHashMap;
    return *bucket[hashIndex];
}
```

I call the function like this (where test is an array of characters)

```
addToBucket(test, getWhichBucket(test, &bucket));
```

the add to bucket looks like this:

```
void addToBucket(char word[], container **bucket){
    container *temp = (struct Container*)malloc (sizeof(struct Container));
    strcpy(temp->key, word);
    temp->value = 9001;
    temp->next = *bucket;
    *bucket = temp;

    return;
}
```

However the compiler issues `warnings` when I `compile` the code and when I `run` it I get a `segmentation error`. Does anyone know why? The warnings can be seen here:

```
cw.c: In function ‘main’:
cw.c:86:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getWhichBucket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
cw.c:37:19: note: expected ‘struct Container ***’ but argument is of type ‘struct Container * (*)[(long unsigned int)(sizeOfHashMap)]’
cw.c:86:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘addToBucket’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
cw.c:56:6: note: expected ‘struct container **’ but argument is of type ‘struct Container *’
```

Comment: What does `addToBucket` look like?

Comment: I posted the code in the main topic as I couldn't get it to format nice in this comment

Comment: Shouldn't struct Container **bucket[10]){ be struct Container **bucket ?

Comment: the argument is suppose to take an array of pointers so shouldn't it be struct Container **bucket[10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
addToBucket(test, getWhichBucket(test, &bucket));
```

is passing a

```
struct Container *(*)[10]
```

to `getWhichBucket`. That's the wrong type, as the compiler says.

You can fix the prototype and implementation

```
struct Container* getWhichBucket(char word[], struct Container *(*bucket)[10]){
    int value = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int size = strlen(word);
    int hashIndex = 0;

    for(i =0; i < size; i++){
      value += (int)word[i];
    }

    //size of array is worked out by getting memory that array takes up / a slot
    hashIndex =  value % sizeOfHashMap;
    return (*bucket)[hashIndex];
}
```

or change the call, but there's no easy way to get a `struct Container **bucket[10]` from a `struct Container *bucket[10]`, so then you'd probably still want to change the type and implementation of `getWhichBucket`.

Since you're not modifying the `bucket` argument there, there's no need to pass the address, you can simply pass the `struct Container *bucket[10]` directly,

```
struct Container* getWhichBucket(char word[], struct Container *bucket[]){
    int value = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int size = strlen(word);
    int hashIndex = 0;

    for(i =0; i < size; i++){
      value += (int)word[i];
    }

    //size of array is worked out by getting memory that array takes up / a slot
    hashIndex =  value % sizeOfHashMap;
    return bucket[hashIndex];
}
```

and call

```
addToBucket(test, getWhichBucket(test, bucket));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your declaration of `addToBucket` from

```
void addToBucket(char word[], container *bucket)
{ 
    container *temp = (struct Container)malloc (sizeof(struct Container)); 
    strcpy(temp->key, word); 
    temp->value = 9001; 
    temp->next = *bucket; 
    *bucket = temp; 
    return; 
}
```

to

```
void addToBucket(char word[], Container *bucket)
{ 
    Container *temp = malloc (sizeof(struct Container)); 
    strcpy(temp->key, word); 
    temp->value = 9001; 
    temp->next = *bucket; 
    *bucket = temp; 
    return; 
}
```

Note the change in case for `Container` -- case matters in C... `container` is not the same thing as `Container`.

Also... note... [you should not cast `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention:

I orginally declared container as this:
typedef struct Container container; 

I just didn't change the methods over I'll edit my code to reflect this.